# Schemacrawler table/column comments/remarks SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, schemacrawler, remarks

I'm using a SQL Server database, my `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` doesn't contain `TABLE` or `COLUMN` comments, I want to add these to a generated output.

So far I've been able to generate a html using a custom query that queries `sys.extended_properties`, but this means I can't generate things like a svg.

Is there a way to have schemacrawler use the info in `sys.extended_properties` and still use the available generation methods?

Comment: Are you using SchemaCrawler programatically, or using the command-line? The answer will be different in each case.

Comment: I'm using the command line, if I use the commandline I have to hardcode the tablename on the commandline. 

I've also tried adding the query to the config file, when I do -command=tables.queryname tablename it uses the wrong table.

when using -command=tables.queryname -tables=<table> I get the error that the multi-part (databasename.schema.tablename) identifier couldn't be found

Comment: For completeness, please include your config file, and command-line.

Comment: @SualehFatehi I have a similar question/issue in trying to figure out how to include extended_properties in the json output from the command-line. Thanks.